# Real Analysis Covid lectures using Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Just wondering if someone can point me to any intro real analysis video lectures that used Rudin. Because of Covid I thought that there might be a lot more out there but a cursory glance doesn't seem to give results.

Comment: While a lot of university courses went over to video lectures, they are usually posted to their own pages, which are frequently not open to search through Google (alas).  Many times I've only turned useful material up with a certain amount of "digging".  The open MIT courses from Fall 2010 [  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100b-analysis-i-fall-2010/ ] and Fall 2012 [ https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100c-real-analysis-fall-2012/ ] used Rudin.

Comment: Sorry, the MIT courses I cited didn't include video lectures back then.  Sets that teach using Rudin include one by Winston Ou (2018) [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ab41LEw9oiI&list=PLun8-Z_lTkC6qJF1sVh3_Hx7aL6FPd0IN ] , and Arkady Etkin (2015?) [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QtSa26C0g&list=PL3bz7bBWUYh51Nvsrs9pguAjx-FDX1Z9o ] .  I don't personally know how helpful you'll find them.

Answer (score 7):

Do you know Francis Su's lectures? I've watched a few on YouTube, and according to his web page he uses Rudin for the course, although I haven't watched enough to know how closely he follows the text.

*"We use the classic text Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin, and cover the first half of the textbook (Chapter 1 to 5, and part of Chapter 7)."*

He's a good lecturer based on what I've seen.

https://math.hmc.edu/su/real-analysis-youtube/

Comment: He acknowledges that the video lectures from 2010 are somewhat blurry, so he linked on his Spring 2020 course page [ https://math.hmc.edu/su/math131/ ] to lecture notes he wrote out for the course when he gave it in 2014 : https://app.box.com/v/su-math-131-fall2014?sortColumn=name&sortDirection=ASC   .  The course page includes the homework he gave at the time.

Comment: Yeah those are fine, it's just that they're too blurry + the lecture format doesn't translate all that well to online video (I find at least.) Covid lectures are specifically designed for video viewing so I wanted to see if there were any examples out there.